# Finding minimum necessary volume of gas container

Tags: c++, algorithm, brute-force

I found this problem somewhere in a contest and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

> There is the N cities with coordinates (x, y). I have to go from first
>   city and reach the second city. There is a gas station in each city.
>   So I have to find minimum necessary volume of gas container to reach
>   the final city.
>   For example:

```
Input:
3
17 4
19 4
18 5
Output:
1.414
```

Here, my way is: `1->3->2`

I'm using simple brute-force method, but it so slow. How can I optimize my code?
Maybe there is a better solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int n, used[203];

double min_dist;

struct pc {
    int x, y;
};

pc a[202];

double find_dist(pc a, pc b) {
    double dist = sqrt( (a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y)*(a.y - b.y) );
    return dist;
}

void functio(double d, int used[], int k, int step) {
    used[k] = 1;
    if(k == 1) {
        if(d < min_dist) {
            min_dist = d;
        }
        used[k] = 0;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if(i != k && used[i] == 0) {
            double temp = find_dist(a[k], a[i]);

            if(temp > d) {
                if(temp < min_dist)
                functio(temp, used, i, step + 1);
            }
            else {
                if(d < min_dist)
                functio(d, used, i, step + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    used[k] = 0;
}

int main() {

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> a[i].x >> a[i].y;

    min_dist = 1000000;
    memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));
    functio(0, used, 0, 0);
    cout << fixed  << setprecision(3) << min_dist << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Consider posting your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is your algorithm actually correct? I mean does it pass the test? Also, how are the cities connected? Are they all connected to all other with a straight-line? Also consider linking the source where you found this problem.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly. Are you required to visit all cities in arbitrary order? do you have a starting and ending city? the problem link would help thanks.

Comment: @hasan83: As state, it just has to go from 1rst city to second city, other cities are just gas stations.

Comment: @hasan83 No it is not required.

Comment: @dingalapadum Algorithm is correct. It just very slow.

Comment: Can you describe your approach instead of the badly-indented and undocumented code? BTW, isn't the the gas volume equivalent to the maximum distance between two refill stops? Then it has to be enough for the longest distance between two refills on the route, which leaves you with the choice when to make a detour with an additional stop in order to reduce that maximum distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum spanning tree has the neat property of encoding all of the paths between vertices that minimize the length of the longest edge on the path. For Euclidean MST, you can compute the Delaunay triangulation and then run your favorite O(m log n)-time algorithm (on a graph with m = O(n) edges) for a total running time of O(n log n). Alternatively, you could run Prim with a naive priority queue for an O(n^2)-time algorithm with a good constant (especially if you exploit SIMD).

Comment: please, check my solution and tell me if something wrong with it. look a correct one.

Comment: I don't need to connect to all cities.

Comment: @James: You may still stop once start and end are in minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @James You don't need the whole tree, just the path between the two cities. It just happens that it's not significantly cheaper to compute only the needed part.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to optimise in your algorithm is *the longest distance you travel between two cities*. Because that's how big your gas tank needs to be.
This is a variation on shortest path, because there you're trying to optimise the enire path length.

I think you could get away with this:

- make a list of edges. (the distance between each pair of cities)
- remove the longest edge from the list, unless this causes the destination to become unreachable.
- once you cannot remove the longest path anymore, that means that this is your limiting factor in going to your destination. The rest of the route doesn't matter anymore.

Then in the end you should have a list of edges that make up a path between source and destination.

I haven't proven this solution to be optimal, so no guarantees. But consider this: if you remove the longest path, there are only shorter paths to take, so the maximum leg distance won't increase.

---

About the complexity, time complexity is `O(n log n)` because you have to sort the edges.
Memory complexity is O(n^2)

This is probably not the most efficient algorithm, because it is a graph-algorithm, and makes no use of the fact that the cities are on an euclidean plane. There is probably some optimisation there...

Comment: You forget to state the complexity to know if destination is reachable. And in your `O(E log E)`, `E` is `V²` (with `E`: edge count and `V`: vertex count.).

Comment: please, check my solution and tell me if something wrong with it. look a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce time complexity to `O(n^2*log(n))` using binary search which will run within the 1 second time limit. The idea behind the binary search is if we can reach city 2 from city 1 using `x` volume there is no need to check for higher volume container. If we cannot reach using using this then we need more than `x` volume. To check if we can reach city 2 using x volume you can use `BFS`. If two cities are within `x` distance of each other then its possible to move from one to the another and we can say they are connected by edge.

Code:

```
int vis[203];
double eps=1e-8;

struct pc {
    double x, y;
};

double find_dist(pc &a, pc &b) {
    double dist=sqrt((a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y)*(a.y - b.y));
    return dist;
}

bool can(vector<pc> &v, double x) {  // can we reach 2nd city with volume x
    int n=v.size();
    vector<vector<int>> graph(n, vector<int>(n, 0));  // graph in adjacency matrix form
    // set edges in graph
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if(i==j) continue;  //same city
            double d=find_dist(v[i], v[j]);
            if(d<=x) graph[i][j]=1; // can reach from city i to city j using x volume
        }
    }


    // perform BFS
    memset(vis, 0, sizeof(vis));
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(0); // we start from city 0 (0 absed index)
    vis[0]=1;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        int top=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(top==1) return true; // can reach city 2 (1 in 0-based index)
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(top!=i && !vis[i] && graph[top][i]==1) {
                q.push(i);
                vis[i]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // can't reach city 2
}


double calc(vector<pc> &v) {  // calculates minimum volume using binary search
    double lo=0, hi=1e18;
    while(abs(hi-lo)>eps) {
        double mid=(lo+hi)/2;
        if(can(v, mid)) {
            hi=mid;   // we need at most x volume
        } else{
            lo=mid;  // we need more than x volumer
        }
    }
    return lo;
}
```